# File in s3 bucket comes with no values when running python script through lambda in aws

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-athena

I have the following script but when the file lands in s3 it comes blank.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
from datetime import datetime
import boto3
import botocore.session as bc

print('Loading function')
client_s3=boto3.client('s3')

def run_athena(BUCKET_NAME, PREFIX):
    client=boto3.client('athena')
    database = 'data_lake'
    query ="SELECT buid, property_id, checkin_date, count(*) number_of_direct_bookings FROM data_lake.vw_qs_bookings_v1 where source_logic in ('sources_phone', 'sources_email', 'sources_website','sources_front_desk') and cancelled_flag=0 and checkin_date= date_add('day', -1, current_date) group by 1,2,3";
    s3_output = 's3://gainsight-file/gainsight/'
    response = client.start_query_execution(QueryString=query, QueryExecutionContext={'Database': database}, ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': s3_output})
   
  
    today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    response_s3 = client_s3.list_objects(
        Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        Prefix=PREFIX,
    )
    name = response_s3["Contents"][0]["Key"]
    client_s3.copy_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, CopySource=BUCKET_NAME+'/'+name, Key=PREFIX+"vw_qs_bookings_v1_"+today)
    client_s3.delete_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=name)
    

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Entered lambda_handler")
    run_athena('gainsight-file', 'gainsight/')
```

I assume there is something to do with the query variable.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.start_query_execution(…)` only *starts* a query execution, it does not wait for it to complete (because that could be up to 30 minutes). You need to call `client.get_query_execution(…)` until you get a response that says the execution is successful (or failed). Only then is the output available.